# assistance with array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Help me to  iterating over array please.

My mysql stored procedure returns the following output when I run it on the command line:

```
mysql> call sp_test();
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| startt   | 2013-04-01 | 2013-04-02 | 2013-04-03 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| 08:00:00 | Donald     | Daisy      | Mickey     |
| 12:00:00 | Pluto      | Goofy      | Minnie     |
| 14:00:00 | NULL       | Mickey     | NULL       |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(This is a dynamic query, the date values in the column headings are not static.)

I can call this stored procedure from php and successfully populate an array which I do thus:

```
  6 <?php
  7 $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db');
  8 $sql = "CALL sp_test()";
  9 $query = $db->query($sql);
 10 $result = array();
 11 while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
 12     $result[] = $row;
 13     }
 14     $query->close();
 15     $db->close();
```

The array contains:
    array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { ["startt"]=> string(8) "08:00:00" ["2013-04-01"]=> string(6) "Donald" ["2013-04-02"]=> string(5) "Daisy" ["2013-04-03"]=> string(6) "Mickey" } [1]=> array(4) { ["startt"]=> string(8) "12:00:00" ["2013-04-01"]=> string(5) "Pluto" ["2013-04-02"]=> string(5) "Goofy" ["2013-04-03"]=> string(6) "Minnie" } [2]=> array(4) { ["startt"]=> string(8) "14:00:00" ["2013-04-01"]=> NULL ["2013-04-02"]=> string(6) "Mickey" ["2013-04-03"]=> NULL } }

My problems begin when I try to iterate over the array (using php) to present the results.

Would you suggest a 'loop' which will iterate over the array and produce the html equivalent of the command line result (as shown at the top of this post)?

I have tried the following which did not do exactly what I wanted, then I became completely confused.  Hope you can help.

```
 17 echo "<table>";
 18 foreach ($result as $value) {
 19     foreach ($value as $key => $data) {
 20         echo "<tr>";
 21         echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";
 22         echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
 23         echo "</tr>";
 24         }
 25         echo "\n";
 26     }
 27 echo "</table>";
 28 //var_dump($query);
 29 ?>
```

Output from this is:

startt  Array

2013-04-01  Array

2013-04-02  Array

2013-04-03  Array

startt  Array

2013-04-01  Array

2013-04-02  Array

2013-04-03  Array

startt  Array

2013-04-01  Array

2013-04-02  Array

2013-04-03  Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner `foreach` is this:

```
foreach ($value as $key => $data) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

The problem is that `$value` is the row and thus an array; when you try to `echo` that it will print `Array` (and raise a notice). Instead, you want `$data` which is the column:

```
    echo "<td>" . $data . "</td>";
```

Also, you should use proper HTML escaping:

```
foreach ($value as $key => $data) {
    printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n",
        htmlspecialchars($key),
        htmlspecialchars($data)
    );
}
```

**Update**

To retain the table format from the query output, you first have to extract the function that prints a whole row:

```
function printRow($data)
{
    echo '<tr>' . join('', array_map(function($item) {
        return sprintf('<td>%s</td>', htmlspecialchars($item));
    }, $data)) . '</tr>';
}
```

Then you have to treat the first row as special:

```
echo '<table>';
$firstRow = true;
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($firstRow) {
        printRow(array_keys($row));
        $firstRow = false;
    }
    printRow($row);
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you @Jack.  Your suggestion has eliminated the error that I was getting, a leap forward.  Finally I would like to interchange where date and time appear.  I want date as column headings and time in the row (first cell).  Presently it is the opposite.  I tried some changes but produced more errors.  If you can suggest how to interchange column and row values then I can mark this post the correct answer.  Thans again for your previous helpful input.`startt 08:00:00
2013-04-01 Donald
2013-04-02 Daisy
2013-04-03 Mickey
startt 12:00:00
2013-04-01 Pluto
2013-04-02 Goofy
2013-04-03 Minnie
`

Comment: sorry that the formatting of the example is lost in my reply.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion.  The code runs but... it is returning `ArrayArrayArrayArray~  Something is not quite right.  could we be referring to the wrong index?

Comment: your solution is ideal, it works just as I wanted it to.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch_assoc()` in a while loop just grabs the row itself, and assumes that you know the column names. Lets say you have columns in your table named `username` and `id`. Your while loop could look something like:

```
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
  $result[] = 'Username: '.$row['username'].', ID: '.$row['id'];
}
```

Maybe you want your code to look like:

```
$rows = $query->fetch_row(); $out = '';
foreach($rows as $r){
  $out .= '<tr>';
  foreach($r as $k => $v){
    $out .= "<td>$k</td><td>$v</td>";
  }
  $out .= '</tr>';
}
echo "<table>$out</table>";
```

P.S.
I didn't use `fetch_assoc()` since there was no point. You just want each row, I got them by their numeric indexes. You don't need to initialize arrays in PHP, before you create them by index, so you don't need to write `$result = array()`. You should also put your `new mysqli()` on a separate, secure page.

Comment: thanks @PHPglue.  so what can I use instead of `fetch_assoc()`?